# Angular 5 - Are callbacks limited in scope?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, callback, promise

Let's say you define a variable like below (`snackbar`). It's accessible by the rest of the Angular class with `this`, but not in the callbacks of promises. I'm using AngularFire 5.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private snackbar: MatSnackBar, private afs: AngularFirestore) {}    

    //Promise function
    this.afs.doc(path).set({
        ...some code
    }).then(function(docRef){
        this.snackbar.open('Snackbar message', 'OK');  //Sanckbar unreachable
    });

    //Regular function
    this.snackbar.open('Snackbar message', 'OK');  //Sanckbar works fine
}
```

How would someone reach those variables from inside the `then`? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: Replace `function(docRef)` with `arrow function`. Your `context` is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a JavaScript "feature"

Use

```
 }).then((docRef) =>{
```

instead of

```
 }).then(function(docRef){
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: That works great, thanks.

Comment: @FiringBlanks glad to hear :)

Comment: Isn't it an EcmaScript feature ?

Comment: @trichetriche I meant `this` not working as most expect with `function () {}` is a JavaScript feature ;-), you're right about `=>`